# Not able to merge in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm trying to do UPSERT(Update or insert) in DB2 AS400. I've followed the guidelines which are specified by IBM. But, it says as MERGE is not valid. Here is my query.

```
MERGE INTO myTable AS tab
USING (VALUES
    (123pk,'6','11','22','33',CURDATE())
) AS merge (TSPK,adf1,adf2,adf3,adf4,adf5)
ON tab.TSPK= merge.TSPK
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET tab.TSPK= merge.TSPK,
               tab.adf1= merge.adf1,
               tab.adf2= merge.adf2,
               tab.adf3= merge.adf3,
              tab.adf4= merge.adf4
              tab.adf5= CURDATE()                  
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TSPK,adf1,adf2,adf3,adf4,adf5 )
    VALUES (merge.TSPK, merge.adf1, merge.adf2,merge.adf3,merge.adf4,CURDATE())
```

The error it throws is

```
 [SQL0104] Token MERGE was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER. [SQL State=42601, DB Errorcode=-104]
```

In DB2, it shows we can use MERGE keyword. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en

Comment: Try changing alias `MERGE` to something else. Maybe it's a problem with reserved word.

Comment: @sagi, there is MERGE keyword used in DB2. Please check https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en

Comment: Not the `MERGE` statement. the `MERGE` alias. -> `(123pk,'6','11','22','33',CURDATE())
) AS merge`

Comment: @sagi, I tried by just keeping as m It shows the same. Even "merge" should not be an issue.

Comment: If your database is on AS/400, you should probably reference the manual for that platform (and the actual version you're using).

Comment: Here's the documentation for `MERGE` on IBM i 7.3:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzmerge.htm

Answer (score 1):

Merge was added to DB2 for i on IBM i version 7.1. If you are on an earlier version (6.1 or earlier) not only is it out of service, but you can't use the `MERGE` statement.